# How to add Mapbox json layers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a leaflet basemap established:

```
var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',

cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18});
var map1 = new L.Map('map', {layers: [cloudmade], center: new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.04), zoom: 6});
```

Now I am trying to use HTML to toggle a few Mapbox json layers:

```
map1 .layers({ 
           1: { api: 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/inosys.1cpsycqc.jsonp',   
              center: {  ease: 1000 }
              },

         2: { 
            api: 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapster88.1.jsonp',
               center: {  ease: 1000 }
         },

         3: {                    
            api: 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapster88.2.jsonp',
              center: {  ease: 1000 }   
        },
```

Here is the test map: http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/taylorpeterh/index19.html

How can I configure the map1 .layers to work with the leaflet L.Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Use [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/), which is a Leaflet plugin that adds TileJSON support and lets you include these layers like `L.mapbox.tileLayer('inosys.1cpsycqc').addTo(map)`
- Add tiles using our XYZ API, as [in this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/plain-leaflet/)